# RSA Encrypting and Decrypting JAVA

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I've been trying to decrypt my encrypted message for a while now, but it isn't working as I'd like it to. I have my outputs for encryption working, but I can't decrypt the encrypted message!

Here are my values:
**P**: 67
**Q**: 71
**PQ**: 4757
**PhiPQ**: 4620
**E**: 13
**D**: 1777

Here is my output for the encrypted message (when 'hello' is entered):
`????` (Which is working fine)

Here is my output for the decrypted message (when 'hello' is entered):
`1109 314 2309 2309 4015` (Which is working, but does not give me back the characters 'hello')

We're supposed to implement this formula into the code **(C^D)%PQ** but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it when decrypting the encrypted message.

I'm not sure what the problem is, here is my code below:

**ENCRYPTION**

```
    String encryptedMessage = "";

    String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a message: ");

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; message.length() > i; i++) {
        char l = message.charAt(i);
        int m = l;
        c = 1;
        int newE = e;

        while (newE > 0) {
            if (newE % 2 != 0) {
                c = ((c * m) % (pq));
            }
            newE = newE / 2;
            m = (((m * m)) % (pq));
        }
        encryptedMessage = encryptedMessage + (char) c;
    }

    System.out.println("Encrypted Message is: " + encryptedMessage);
```

**DECRYPTION**

```
    String decryptedMessage = "";

    c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; encryptedMessage.length() > i; i++) {
        char l = encryptedMessage.charAt(i);
        int m = l;
        c = 1;
        int newE = e;

        while (newE > 0) {
            if (newE % 2 != 0) {
                c = ((c * m) % (pq));
            }
            newE = newE / 2;
            m = (((m * m)) % (pq));
        }
        decryptedMessage = decryptedMessage + " " + (c);
    }

    // prints out 'decryptedMessage' value
    System.out.println("Decrypted Message is: " + decryptedMessage);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't delete your question when you get a helpful response. Stack Overflow is a site where others can find existing answers to similar questions. Instead, click the green check mark next to the most helpful answer to accept it.

Comment: This question uses the Chinese Remainder Theorem to calculate the private key part. This also means that avh is wrong, you don't need the private exponent d. You can solve it using exponent d, but that's probably not the way to go.

Comment: Do you get any negative values anywhere during encryption / decryption? Usually these calculations are performed either using modular exponentiation and `BigInteger`. `int` in Java is a 32 bit signed number, `(x * y) % n` may not be identical  to what you expect if you just look at the math.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for encryption and decryption look, well, *symmetric*. That's not the trick with RSA. In RSA, you have the public key `e` for encryption and the private key `d` for decryption. I don't even see `d` in your decryption code?!

Comment: Oh, that's the problem! However, where should I place the **(C^D)%PQ** formula?

Comment: @Dongbae No it isn't the problem. RSA is the same in both directions, just with the other key.

Comment: @EJP, Could you give me an example? I'm really frustrated with this.

Comment: So you call the code above with different values for `e`?

Comment: Hm, so do you, or do you not continue on the same code for both the encryption and decryption processes? I'd like to understand.

Answer (score 0):

@EJP was right.

I put in the decryption key and it worked perfectly! So, instead of my encryption key being `newE`, I switched it with `newD` and it finally works now. It was a stupid, small mistake on my part. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: If avh solved your issue then you should give him the credits & accept, not post an answer of your own. I don't see what this answer brings in addition to avh's answer.

Comment: @avh was wrong: I was right. I don't see how you can describe that as solving your own problem.